# paintevent in continuous loop?

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyside

I have the following code which draws ellipse on the circumference of a circle and then draws chords between ellipses. The chords are drawn fine but the event bombs on me and goes into a infinite loop.

```
def binomial(i, n):

    return math.factorial(n) / float(
    math.factorial(i) * math.factorial(n - i))


def bernstein(t, i, n):

    return binomial(i, n) * (t ** i) * ((1 - t) ** (n - i))


def bezier(t, points):

    n = len(points) - 1
    x = y = 0
    for i, pos in enumerate(points):
        bern = bernstein(t, i, n)
        x += pos[0] * bern
        y += pos[1] * bern
   return x, y


def bezier_curve_range(n, points):

    for i in xrange(n):
        t = i / float(n - 1)
        yield bezier(t, points)

def getControlPt(x1, y1, x2, y2, t):

    new_px = (1 - t) * x1 + t * x2
    new_py = (1 - t) * y1 + t * y2
    return new_px, new_py


class Temp1(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, c, parent=None):
        super(Temp1, self).__init__(parent)
        self.text = "Hi"
        self.cords = c

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        qp = QPainter(self)
        qp.setPen(Qt.red)

        bluePen = QPen(Qt.blue, 1, Qt.DashLine)
        steps = 10000

        for i in range(15):
            for j in range(15):
              if i == j:
                  continue
              px, py = getControlPt(self.cords[i][0], self.cords[i][1], self.cords[j][0], self.cords[j][1], 0.55)
              px1, py1 = getControlPt(px, py, self.cords[j][0], self.cords[j][1], 0.25)
              px2, py2 = getControlPt(px1, py1, self.cords[j][0], self.cords[j][1], 0.75)

              cp = (self.cords[i], (px, py) , (px1, py1), (px2, py2), self.cords[j])
              oldPoint = cp[0]
              qp.setPen(bluePen)

              for point in bezier_curve_range(steps, cp):
                   qp.drawLine(oldPoint[0], oldPoint[1], point[0], point[1])
                   oldPoint = point




class Temp(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h, theta, cords, parent=None):
        super(Temp, self).__init__(parent)
        self.w = w
        self.h = h
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.text = "test"
        self.angle = theta
        self.cords = cords

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        qp = QPainter(self)
        qp.setPen(Qt.red)
        qp.drawEllipse(0, 0, self.w - 2, self.h -2)




class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.cords = []
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.setWindowTitle('Points')
        self.drawP()



    def drawP(self):
        theta = 2 * np.pi / 15
        for i in range(15):
            angle = theta * (i + 1)

            dx = int(round(400 + 300 * np.cos(angle)))
            dy = int(round(400 + 300 * np.sin(angle)))
            self.cords.append((dx, dy))
        for i in range(15):    
            t = Temp(self.cords[i][0], self.cords[i][1], 45, 20, np.degrees(angle), self.cords, parent=self)
            t.setGeometry(self.cords[i][0], self.cords[i][1] , 45, 20)
        t1 = Temp1(self.cords, parent = self)
        t1.setGeometry(0, 0, 800, 600)



app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = Example()
ex.setGeometry(0, 0, 800, 600)
ex.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The problem is with the paintevent function of class Temp1.

Comment: Do not call `setGeometry` from `paintEvent` - it's a logic error.

Comment: I can't test Temp1.paintEvent because I don't have the functions you use, but the rest of the code looks fine. May be the problem is somewhere else. Have you considered using `QGraphicsView`? It's more convenient for your task. You wouldn't have to subclass anything and reimplement paint events. Also Qt supports Bezier curves (e.g. `QPainterPath::cubicTo`).

Comment: @PavelStrakhov Hi I have added the code for bezier curves, let me know if that helps you in finding out what might be happening.

Answer (score 0):

If you throw a `print 'Temp1.paintEvent', e, i, j` inside the nested for loops inside of `Temp1.paintEvent`, you'll see that it's not hanging, it's just slow, and every time you hide the window, then bring it back up, it has to go through the whole paintEvent again before actually showing it. If you're patient the window will eventually pop up.